# List of resources to learn cassandra

Tags: resources, list, cassandra

Lately I have been reading a lot of blog topics about big sites(facebook, twitter, digg, reddit to name a few) using cassandra as their datastore instead of MysqL.

I would like to gather a list of resources to learn using cassandra. Hopefully some videos or podcasts explaining how to use cassandra.

### My list

- [Twissandra](http://github.com/ericflo/twissandra) - Twissandra is an example project, created to learn and demonstrate how to use Cassandra. Running the project will present a website that has similar functionality to Twitter
- [WTF is a supercolumn](http://arin.me/post/40054651676/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model) - WTF is a SuperColumn? An Intro to the Cassandra Data Model

I hope there are resources to watch howto use cassandra.

Many thanks,
Alfred

Comment: Please make it a community wiki (edit check community wiki) as it otherwise might get deleted.

Comment: did you see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArticlesAndPresentations ?

Comment: @jbellis, yes I did :) and it is a nice page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these articles really helpful coming from the relational world:

- <del>http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=80</del>
- <del>http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=108</del>
- <del>http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=207</del>

Right now the docs available for cassandra is limited in some places. I've been watching the Cassandra user and dev email list like a hawk. That seems to be where most of the FAQ's live.

Comment: These links seem to be dead. Does anyone know alternative links or what the new location is?

Comment: These were to "Installing and using Apache Cassandra With Java" by  Ronald Mathies. It's on archive.org, but I think that Cassandra documentation and wiki might be more up-to-date and useful. (I think that they were the only thing written about Cassandra at one point). http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/